# Alternate methods for getting coefficients from PipeLineModel of family "binomial?"

Tags: r, apache-spark, logistic-regression, summary

Environment.

R: 3.2.2 "Fire Safety" 
Spark: 1.5.2

```
> obj <- glm(response ~ . , family = "binomial", data = df )

> class(df)

[1] "DataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

> class(obj)

[1] "PipelineModel"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

> summary(model)
```

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No features names available for LogisticRegressionModel

So I know summary(PipelineModel) will not work if PipeLineModel is of family binomial (Logistic Regression Model), but I need the coefficients from this model. Although, predict(PipelineModel, data = df ) will work on PipeLineModel of family binomial. Anybody have any alternative methods of extracting the coefficients from the PipeLineModel of family binomial?

Comment: Ugly workaround is to use internal API `SparkR:::callJStatic("org.apache.spark.ml.api.r.SparkRWrappers", "getModelWeights", x@model)` where `x` is your model. Otherwise you have to wait for [SPARK-9492](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9492) to be resolved but it looks like you already know that.

Comment: I have 81 columns in my spark dataFrame, all categorical variables were transformed to be dummy variables prior to being stored in the dataFrame (data was originally stored in textFile). The dataFrame is built correctly, and data is there when I do collect(df). When I build my glm object of family binomial, the object is built. But when I call the SparkR API function callJStatic, The error returned is.   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No weights available for LogisticRegressionModel Is this a singularity issue with the model? I have baselines for all dummy vars @zero323

Comment: I don't think so. Spark `glm` doesn't try to solve the problem analytically so in the worst case scenario weights should be completely off. Can you provide exact code you use?

Comment: Could I message or email you the code? @zero323 Thanks for your help

Comment: So I changed my glm object to type gaussian which is linear. Technically speaking, cannot I not just do summary(glm_guassian_object), and use these coefficients, as they should be the same for binomial (logistic), but I would just have to plug in coefficients in 1/(1 - e^-t), where t is equivalent to linear model. Btw, summary(glm_guassian_works) and returns coefficients. @zero323

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow and let you know if I figure something out. Regarding email you'll find my public email on my GitHub account. Most of the traffic goes to spam but I check it once in a while :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W2VC0mYP new link to code, other expired. Thanks

Comment: OK, it looks like, I used wrong build yesterday and it doesn't work on 1.5.x after all :(

Comment: This is very unfortunate that sparkR does not have support for the most basic R operations such as summary, on a Logistic Regression Model. Looks like well have to wait. Thanks for your help @zero332

Comment: Well, truth be told SparkR is just an experimental quality software and probably shouldn't be included in the main Spark yet.